# Custom Popup Dialog Glitching

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, popup

I have these "cards" on my page that are basically just divs with some stuff in them. When you click a card a popup dialog appears. The popping up is working just fine. However, the rest of the page is screwed up because when a card is clicked, an extra scrollbar appears inexplicably on my pages body element(I think), and the default scrollbar is disabled! This scroll bar causes all the elements on my page to resize to compensate, and they all shift ever so slightly to the left. When I exit out of the dialog, the extra scroll bar disappear and the default one goes back to normal, all the page elements go back to there normal spots. Except there's just one problem: My nav bar no longer extends the length of the page! It ends where the extra scroll bar would be if it was still there. Also, when using a default alert dialog (no custom pop-up box template) I am not having this problem. Why is this happening? How do I fix it?

Code - Formatting is a little messed up from my copy/pasting.

This is the html for the tab that is having the issue. It is bound to the starting html page with a directive and appears when it's corresponding tab is clicked.

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-1"></div>
<div id="badges-div" class="col-md-10">
    <h3 class="tile-header">Your Badges</h3>
    <div class="badges-table">
        <div ng-repeat="badge in earnedBadges" class="table-badge-div" ng-click="showBadge($event, badge)">

            <img ng-src="images/{{badge.image}}" class="badge-card-image">
            <div class="badge-card-bottom">
                <p class="badge-card-title">{{badge.name}}</p>
            </div>
            <p class="badge-card-points"><b>{{badge.points}}</b></p>
            <p class="badge-card-date"><b>{{badge.earnedDate}}</b></p>
            <img src="images/all_white.png" class="badge-highlight-image">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-xs-1"></div>
</div>
```

Here is the controller where the dialog is created:

```
app.controller("learningController", function($scope, $mdDialog) {
$scope.trackProgress = 38;
$scope.currentTrack = "Software Developer";
$scope.badgeIndex = null;
$scope.userName = "Isaac Way";
$scope.recentBadge = null;
$scope.completedCourses = testCompletedCourses();


$scope.earnedBadges = window.earnedBadges;

$scope.showBadge = function(ev, badge) {
    $mdDialog.show({
        controller: DialogController,
        templateUrl: "templates/badgeDialog.html",
        parent: angular.element(document.body),
        targetEvent: ev,
        clickOutsideToClose: true,
        fullscreen: false
    }); 
};

function DialogController($scope, $mdDialog) {
    $scope.hide = function() { $mdDialog.hide(); };
    $scope.cancel = function() { $mdDialog.cancel(); };
};

// Some irrelevant code here...

};
```

And finally the dialog box template itself:

```
<md-dialog aria-label="Dialog">
    <div>divdivdivdivdiv</div>
</md-dialog>
```

Heres what it looks like when the dialog is popped up - Notice the pointless extra scroll bar next to the normal one.

[image: Popup Glitch]

Comment: it would help for you to post your code. Edit your question and add it all there

Comment: And if you can, a jsfiddle to reproduce the error or behaviour

Comment: I'll post relevant code thank you.